# сделать невидимым checkbox в listview

Tags: java, android

как сделать невидимый checkbox в listview в первом item?
делаю это так, но ничего не происходит

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, listFiles);
                m_listViewLocal.setAdapter(adapter);
                m_listViewLocal.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                ((CheckBox)m_listViewLocal.getAdapter().getItem(0)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `getItem()` адаптера возвращает данные айтема , а не его `View`

Если видимостью надо управлять , то используйте следующий код:

`mlistViewLocal.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.checkbox).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

то есть , мы получаем `View` из первой позиции списка , затем находим в нем наш чекбокс и ставим ему свойство `INVISIBLE` /
Следует заметить , что в стандартой разметке [simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml](https://code.google.com/p/pdn-slatedroid/source/browse/trunk/eclair/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml?r=44) используется виджет `CheckedTextView` , для которого нельзя сделать невидимым только чекбокс без дополнительных ухищрений . Для того , чтобы получить этот элемент нужно искать его по `android.R.id.text1` . Рекомендую использовать свою разметку с отдельным чекбоксом.

Если нужно просто отключить его в первом айтеме , то в методе `getView()` адаптера пишите (опять же для `CheckedTextView` это не подходит):

```
@Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 ...
  if (position==0) mCheckbox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

где `mCheckbox` - ссылка на чекбокс в адаптере

PS: согласно соглашений по обозначению полей классов в Java - имя поля класса начинается с `m` затем следует название поля с большой буквы , например - mCheckbox , никакого нижнего подчеркивания для разделения не надо - привыкайте сразу следовать этим принципам .